# Azure database for MySQL DB 5.7 Transient handling in .net core

Tags: mysql, azure, asp.net-core, azure-database-mysql, azure-mysql-database

I am creating .net core 2.1 MVC application and using Azure database for  MySQL DB 5.7.

I have read below links but seems they are applicable for MS SQL DB.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-high-availability

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific

Transient handling for MySQL not possible? Help me link to MYSQL related similar pages.

Answer (score 0):

A transient error, also known as a transient fault, is an error that will resolve itself. Most typically these errors manifest as a connection to the database server being dropped. Also new connections to a server can't be opened. Transient errors can occur for example when hardware or network failure happens.

Transient errors should be handled using retry logic. Situations that must be considered:

- An error occurs when you try to open a connection
- An idle connection is dropped on the server side. When you try to issue a command it can't be executed
- An active connection that currently is executing a command is dropped.

The first and second case are fairly straight forward to handle. Try to open the connection again. When you succeed, the transient error has been mitigated by the system. You can use your Azure Database for MySQL again. We recommend having waits before retrying the connection. Back off if the initial retries fail. This way the system can use all resources available to overcome the error situation. A good pattern to follow is:

- Wait for 5 seconds before your first retry.
- For each following retry, the increase the wait exponentially, up to 60 seconds.
- Set a max number of retries at which point your application considers the operation failed.

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/mysql/concepts-connectivity#handling-transient-errors).

And you can read more on how to troubleshoot connection issues to Troubleshoot connection issues to Azure Database for MySQL [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/mysql/howto-troubleshoot-common-connection-issues).

Comment: Thanks @Nishan. These are good pointers. They are taking me to admin. I need some links that help me in development code , similar to links i mentioned  in my query but they are for MS SQL.

Comment: one more sample link https://rehansaeed.com/optimally-configuring-entity-framework-core/  this is for MS SQL, i am looking for something related but for MySQL